# Drop down option for a graph in dashboard of grafana

Tags: grafana

[image: Grafana dashboard(screenshot)]

Attached image shows the graph in dashboard which has two graph overlapped.
I want to put a drop down option to it so that I can select one at a time.
 Sometimes I have more than 10 samples or graph in one so I would like to go with this approach or something similar option.

I tried the default option we have at the bottom of the graph, but if I have n number of graphs in one that wont help me. I couldn't understand how to get this done.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: continuation of question  based on the  problem faced -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827803/how-to-get-more-than-one-graph-of-samplers-which-i-have-in-my-jmeter-in-a-grap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are describing the templating function. Take a look at this link: [link](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/)

Like you can see in the screenshot of one of my dashboards. With the help of templating I can select between different query's to show in the graph:
[image]

In your case the query would look something like:

```
SELECT count("responsecode") FROM "samples" WHERE "label" = /^$YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME$/ AND ...
```

Comment: you are customizing one graph right using template. if you select All ,all 3 requests will appear on the graph ??

Comment: yes. In my case if I select "All" all 3 are displayed. But you can select just two also. Like you can see here: http://docs.grafana.org/img/v2/multi-select.gif

Comment: WOW  !! thats what i wanted badly

Comment: can u please tell me how it can be created.for the query                                   SELECT count("responsecode") FROM "samples" WHERE "label" = '1' AND "status" = 'Success' AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1s)

Comment: im getting an error ""error parsing query: missing parameter: timeFilter""

Comment: go to your dashboard -> manage dashboard -> templating -> new. Type=query and the query would look something like this: "SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY=label" This should give you a dropdown with the different labels you have. Then for the graph add the query I posted in my answer.

Comment: h..Im not getting multiple graphs in one ..on selecting multiple values from drop down...if i select 1 and 2 as label name from drop down ,response of both will get added up and im getting total response of that.But i want to view response of 1  as well as 2 ..

Comment: @shey please create a new question with a screenshot of your templating settings, your query in the graph and a screenshot of your result. The comment section is not meant to solve additional problems which are not related to your original question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827803/how-to-get-more-than-one-graph-of-samplers-which-i-have-in-my-jmeter-in-a-grap  i haveasked as a new question.Can you please help me. Attached required screenshot as well.