# How to get more than one graph of samplers (which i have in my jmeter) in a graph of grafana using templating

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, grafana

Im trying to get **throughput/sec** of **each samples** (i have in my **jmeter test**) in **grafana dashboard** using **influxdb**.

I'm using **templating**  to configure .[screenshot showing template settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMvMh.png)

My query is--

```
SELECT count("responsecode") 
FROM "samples" 
WHERE "label" =~ /$label/ 
AND "status" =~ /$status$/ 
AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval)
```

My intention is to get **drop down option** to select graph or response of **one or more samplers** in **a graph of grafana dashboard**.

When i select more than one samplers from drop down i should get response for both.
Attached the response what i'm getting after selecting sampler 1 and 2.What i'm getting is, total response of 1 and 2 as you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fiqzo.png)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve it.

What i was missing is in the query part in graph i missed **group by tag name**.

In my case its group by **tag(label)** . and that solves the issue.